# Having trouble opening a file using ifstream

Tags: c++

I need some help with opening a file and parsing it but i have an issue with `ifstream` not opening the file.  The names of the files are being passed correctly with the extension.

The problem lies in that `myFile.open(file);` doesn't seem to 'actually open' the file since i'm getting constant `Could not open file` output.

**EDITED CODE!!!**
Reason: I noticed it wasn't taking the full file path in when it was checking for the file; it now correctly identifies where the files are, however, still will not open them.

Here's what i'm working with:

```
#include "Parser.h"

using namespace std;

Parser::Parser() {};

void Parser::parseFile(std::string dir, const char* file)
{
    dir = dir + "\\" + std::string(file);
    cout << dir;
    //cout << dir;
    ifstream myFile;

    myFile.open(file);
    if (! myFile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open file " << myFile <<endl;
        //exit(3);
    }
}
```

**Please note that i've tried adding std:: in front of the declaration of my fstream myFile and it still doesn't work.**

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the chmod attributes of the file ?

Comment: does the file exist? do you have appropriate rights for reading the file?

Comment: ifstream myFile (file, ifstream::in);

Comment: You can use OS specific function to determine the issue (like perror() for unixes)

Comment: @Thomas: Adding `ifstream::in` isn't needed since the `ifstream` constructor always adds `ios_base::in` to the mode.

Comment: The files are rw.  The files definitely exist.

Comment: I like how the dir is `std::string` and file is `const char*`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "Parser.h"

using namespace std;

Parser::Parser() {};

void Parser::parseFile(std::string dir, const char* file)
{
    dir = dir + "\\" + std::string(file);
    cout << dir;
    //cout << dir;
    ifstream myFile;

    myFile.open(file);
    if (! myFile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open file " << myFile <<endl;
        //exit(3);
    }
}
```

The line: `myFile.open(file);` needed to be changed to `myFile.open(dir);`

Really dumb mistake, sorry for the trouble.